# Remove square bracketed citation in my reference list while using cite package for citations

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, brackets, apacite

I would like to remove the duplicate of square bracketed citation in my bibliography list and start with just the name and year. I am using the `cite` package, and the `\bibliographystyle{apalike}`, with Citavi reference editor. I've seen this question a lot and the common answer is to use `natbib` package instead. This is good idea however then I need to change all of the `\cite` in the document to `\citep` in order to have it in parentheses. And I am finished my entire (90 page) document (I know I should have fixed this at the beginning).. Is there a way to change them within the `cite` package? Or else is there an easy way to switch all of the `\cite` to `\citep`?

I should also note that I am a very beginner with Latex.

[image]

Comment: Welcome, please add `\usepackage{apacite}` or `\usepackage{natbib}`  to your preamble. If this doesn't give you good results, please provide a [minimal working example](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/minexample/index.html) (<- Link) that let's us reproduce your issue and gives the perfect test case to provide a fitting solution.

Comment: For a quick and dirty way of letting `cite` react as `citep` use: `\let\cite\citep`

Comment: Hi Johannes, That could be a good option! Since I am short of time before a deadline. Just so I understand correctly where should i include that command? In the preamble when i'm setting the new commands?

Comment: `\usepackage[square]{natbib}`  instead of `\usepackage{cite}` and `\let\cite\citep` right in the next line.

Comment: @Johannes_B -- For a not-so-dirty way of making `\cite` act like `\citep`, load the package `letltxmacro` and issue the instruction `\LetLtxMacro\cite\citep`. (Using `\let` to reset a LateX macro that takes optional arguments (as `\citep` does) is an accident waiting to happen...)

Comment: @Mico Yes, completely right. I tend to forget that, as i don't use `\let`. Wait, i just did in another answer. Ooops :-(

Answer (score 1):

The `apalike` bibliography style can only produce authoryear-style citation call-outs, whereas the `cite` package is meant to be used exclusively with bibliography styles that produce numeric-style citation call-outs. Thus, if you need to use the `apalike` bibliography style, do *not* use the `cite` package.

You should load either the `apalike` or the `natbib` citation management package. The former is older, but has the "virtue" (such as it is) of making `\cite` generate "parenthetic" citation call-outs automatically. The `natbib` package is much newer and far more versatile than the `apalike` package. Its "downside", for your purposes at least, is that `\cite` behaves like `\citet`, i.e., it produces "text-style" rather than "parenthetic" citation callouts. I can think of two "fixes":

- Do a global search-and-replace of all instances of `\cite{` in your document, replacing them with `\citep{`. (I strongly recommend this "fix".)
- Load the `letltxmacro` package and issue the instruction

  ```
  \LetLtxMacro\cite\citep
  ```

  in the preamble. (The `\citep` macro takes optional arguments; as such, using `\let` to assign it to `\cite` may produce weird and unpleasant errors.)

An MWE that uses the `natbib` package:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{test, author = "Anne Author", title = "Thoughts", year = 3001}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib,letltxmacro}
\LetLtxMacro\cite\citep % make '\cite' act like `\citep`
\bibliographystyle{apalike}

\begin{document}
\cite[see][p.~45]{test}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```